# combine php code with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, counter, visitor-pattern

I have php code and jQuery/javascript. I want to make visitor counter using jQuery and php code.

Here is the php code :

```
<?php 
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");

if(!$handle){
    echo "could not open the file" ; 
} else { 
    $counter = (int ) fread($handle,20); 
    fclose ($handle);
    $counter++; 
    //echo $counter; 
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ); 
    fwrite($handle,$counter) ; 
    fclose ($handle) ; 
} 
?>
```

and this is jQuery/javascript code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counter.js"></script>

<link href="js/jquery.counter-analog.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <span id="custom"></span>
  <script>
     $('#custom').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
       //direction: 'up',
       interval: '1',
       format: '99999'
       //stop: '2012'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I combine the jQuery/javascript code into php code? This is my first time for using jQuery, and I still don't understand to use jQuery. So I need your help. :D Thank you.

This is the result:

[image]

I want to add "50" into the jQuery "00000", so the result is "00050"

Comment: The best way to mix them is using AJAX. Look for any example of AJAX in JQuery. AJAX sends data between the ".html" page and the ".php" without reloading the webpage.

Comment: It can be done using `ajax`  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: In your case it seems you just need `<?PHP echo $counter; ?>` somewhere on your page unless you want the counter to count up WHILE each user is visiting, e.g. update the counter on one page when another user visits at the same time

Comment: hmmm ... i have <?php echo $counter; ?> in my php code, but the question is, how to get value from php code and set in into the jquery code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to echo the counter value in the span element.
So assuming your PHP code is at the top of the file, it should look like this.

```
<?php 
$handle = fopen("counter.txt", "r");

if(!$handle){
    echo "could not open the file" ; 
} else { 
    $counter = (int ) fread($handle,20); 
    fclose ($handle);
    $counter++; 
    //echo $counter; 
    $handle = fopen("counter.txt", "w" ); 
    fwrite($handle,$counter) ; 
    fclose ($handle) ; 
} 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.counter.js"></script>

<link href="js/jquery.counter-analog.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <span id="custom"><?php echo $counter; ?></span>
  <script>
     $('#custom').addClass('counter-analog').counter({
       //direction: 'up',
       interval: '1',
       format: '99999'
       //stop: '2012'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah.. you're almost right. but now the problem is, the counter runs very fast like a timer and after that the counter set back into "00000" . hmmm is this my fault that i got wrong jquery plugin? because its runs like a timer, so fast...

Comment: this problem already solved. thanks for your help Amon Bigham. i follow your instruction to echo the counter into span element, and then uncomment stop:'2012'..